# Python group by column and value_counts on all other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am dealing with a df of this kind:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'GROUP': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C','A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C','B', 'B', 'C', 'C','A'], 'CATEGORY': ['ORANGE', 'WHITE', 'WHITE','ORANGE','ORANGE','BLACK', 'WHITE', 'BLACK', 'BROWN','BLACK','ORANGE','BLACK', 'WHITE', 'WHITE', 'WHITE', 'BLACK', 'BLACK'], 
                   'SHAPE':['SQUARE','TRIANGLE','SQUARE','CIRCLE','CIRCLE','CIRCLE','SQUARE','CIRCLE','TRIANGLE','CIRCLE','CIRCLE','SQUARE','CIRCLE','TRIANGLE','CIRCLE','SQUARE','CIRCLE']})

df.head()

  GROUP CATEGORY SHAPE
0   A   ORANGE  SQUARE
1   A   WHITE   TRIANGLE
2   B   WHITE   SQUARE
3   B   ORANGE  CIRCLE
4   C   ORANGE  CIRCLE
```

I am trying to group by `GROUP` and do a value counts on all the columns in the df, keeping the top n occurrences. So here's an example on a single column:

```
df.groupby('GROUP')['CATEGORY'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True).head(2)).to_frame()

               CATEGORY
GROUP       
A      WHITE    0.400000
       BLACK    0.400000
B      WHITE    0.500000
       BROWN    0.166667
C      BLACK    0.500000
       ORANGE   0.333333
```

But my desired output would be to append all the value_counts, like so:

```
                CATEGORY          SHAPE
GROUP       
A      WHITE    0.400000  CIRCLE   0.400000
       BLACK    0.400000  SQUARE   0.400000 
B      WHITE    0.500000  CIRCLE   0.500000
       BROWN    0.166667  TRIANGLE 0.333333
C      BLACK    0.500000  CIRCLE   0.666667
       ORANGE   0.333333  SQUARE   0.333333
```

And ideally rename the columns to:

```
       CATEGORY PERC      SHAPE    PERC
GROUP       
A      WHITE    0.400000  CIRCLE   0.400000
       BLACK    0.400000  SQUARE   0.400000 
B      WHITE    0.500000  CIRCLE   0.500000
       BROWN    0.166667  TRIANGLE 0.333333
C      BLACK    0.500000  CIRCLE   0.666667
       ORANGE   0.333333  SQUARE   0.333333
```

Any idea?

Comment: do you have many values or just Shape & Category?

Comment: This is just an example, in the original df I have multiple categorical vars I would like to include.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `.stack()`

and `.concat()` within a list comp to handle each unique column type. `SHAPE`, `CATEGORY`

However, this solution could handle up to n number of unique types.

```
s = df.set_index('GROUP').stack()\
      .groupby(level=[0,1])\
      .value_counts(normalize=True).groupby(level=[0,1]).head(2) #< change 2 for your val.
```

---

```
dfs = pd.concat([s[s.index.isin([i],1)].reset_index()\
                                       .rename(columns={'level_2' : i, 0  : 'PERC'})\
                                       .drop('level_1',1).set_index('GROUP')
                 for i in s.index.get_level_values(1).unique()],axis=1)


print(dfs)

     CATEGORY      PERC     SHAPE      PERC
GROUP                                       
A        BLACK  0.400000    CIRCLE  0.400000
A        WHITE  0.400000    SQUARE  0.400000
B        WHITE  0.500000    CIRCLE  0.500000
B        BLACK  0.166667  TRIANGLE  0.333333
C        BLACK  0.500000    CIRCLE  0.666667
C       ORANGE  0.333333    SQUARE  0.333333
```

Comment: This solution works fine in the first part, which would probably be already good enough. Nonetheless, when I try to apply the pd.concat part on a df with 2+ columns to run value_counts() on, I get ValueError: Shape of passed values is (9, 24), indices imply (3, 24). I can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass each groupby `GROUP` object into the function.
2. Calculate `.value_counts()` on both `CATEGORY` and `SHAPE`
3. Concatenate both `CATEGORY` and `SHAPE` together. `axis=1` is important to make the data line up on the same row.

```
def group_my_data(x):
    category = x['CATEGORY'].value_counts(normalize=True).rename_axis('CATEGORY').reset_index(name='PERC')
    shape = x['SHAPE'].value_counts(normalize=True).rename_axis('SHAPE').reset_index(name='PERC')
    return pd.concat([category, shape], axis=1).head(2)

df = df.groupby('GROUP', as_index=True).apply(group_my_data).reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
```

[image]

Comment: @Kauber does it matter if your groups are exactly in the same order as your desired output example? You'll notice the values in Group A in my solution are swapped.